# Check in via Sharing Dialog PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, checkin, hotspot, publish-actions, share-open-graph

The `publish_actions` permission is deprecated. This permission was very good for implementing Check-in via the `place` parameter. In the `place` parameter it was possible to put the `Page ID` and the `Check in` to be registered in the Page and also in the User Timeline.

Now we only have the option of `Sharing Dialog` which is very limited. I have not yet found any solution so that users can check in via Dialog Sharing. I want to implement this function in a custom Wi-Fi Hotspot. Does anyone have a solution?

Video example: https://wificem.com.br/video/hotspot-checkin.mp4

Comment: I don’t think there currently is a way to do that. (And the times when people cared about their friends “checking in” to a wi-fi hot spot are probably over anyway.)

Comment: If Facebook makes a function obsolete, Facebook had to provide another function that is equivalent. This was correct. Many people depended on this function to work. Unfortunate.